# How do I press keys in selenium vba ? (chrome)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I try these methods but none of them work.

`Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("/html/body").SendKeys (Space)`

`Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("anyxpath").SendKeys (keys.Space)`

`Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("anyxpath").SendKeys.keys.Space)`

`Mydoc.FindElementByXPath("anyxpath").keys.Space)`

can you help me for this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Press Enter and Down arrow key in VBA-Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767433/press-enter-and-down-arrow-key-in-vba-selenium)

Comment: I read this post but I wonder if there is a direct method? . without downloading an additional package.

Comment: you should provide details on what didn't work e.g. where there error messages associated with any/all of these? Would it have been possible to create a minimal reproducible example for us?

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is the correct one but you have to declare the keys class first, e.g. `Dim keys As New Selenium.keys`.
Obviously this is not needed if you're sending a string like `.SendKeys "something"` or `.SendKeys Range("A1").Value`.
There's a hefty documentation included with SeleniumBasic by the way.